# Selecting a row in QTableWidget with conditions to disable pushButton

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I'm not sure if the title is correct but this is the situation:


[image: id 1]



[image: id 2]



[image: id 3]

When a row is selected and contains Application Status of `FULL_MEMBER`,
A pushButton is enabled else it is disabled.

Comment: More information would be needed, I think.
Is the QPushButton to be shown inside the row or somewhere else in the application?

Comment: @AieMPhy, the problem is not clearly stated with relevant code?

Comment: You could connect to the [`selectionChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) signal of the `QTreeWidget`'s [selection model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel).  The button state is then just a function of the current selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the text of the item (cell) in the fifth column of the selected row, each time the selection changes.

Have a slot like this in your widget:

```
private slots:
    void tableSelectionChanged();
```

In the widget constructor, connect it to the table widget signal itemSelectionChanged:

```
connect(ui->tableWidget, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()), this, SLOT(tableSelectionChanged()));
```

The slot definition is like this:

```
//retrieve a list of all selected rows
QModelIndexList list = ui->tableWidget->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
if(list.size() > 0)
{
    //retrieve the index of the first (and only, maybe?) selected row
    int row = list[0].row();
    const int col = 4; //Application Status column id
    QTableWidgetItem * item = ui->tableWidget->item(row, col); //the item we want to inspect
    ui->pushButton->setEnabled( item->text() == "FULL_MEMBER" );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this,
the problem has been solved